# php function wont work twice within a loop

Tags: php, mysql, function, while-loop

I have found a very smart bit of code for calculating driving time and distance using google maps when giving two parameters. i am using it to create a mileage report using data stored in the database.

My problem is i need to use this function twice within the same loop however when i do this it closes the loop and displays no information at all.

Please see the function below

```
function get_driving_information($start, $finish, $raw = false)
{
if(strcmp($start, $finish) == 0)
{
    $time = 0;
    if($raw)
    {
        $time .= ' seconds';
    }

    return array('distance' => 0, 'time' => $time);
}

$start  = urlencode($start);
$finish = urlencode($finish);

$distance   = 'unknown';
$time       = 'unknown';

$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.$start.'&destination='.$finish.'&sensor=false';
if($data = file_get_contents($url))
{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

    if(isset($xml->route->leg->duration->value) AND (int)$xml->route->leg->duration->value > 0)
    {
        if($raw)
        {
            $distance = (string)$xml->route->leg->distance->text;
            $time     = (string)$xml->route->leg->duration->text;
        }
        else
        {
            $distance = (int)$xml->route->leg->distance->value / 1000 / 1.609344;
            $time     = (int)$xml->route->leg->duration->value/ 60;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Could not find that route');
    }

    return array('distance' => $distance, 'time' => $time);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception('Could not resolve URL');
}
}

try
{
$info = get_driving_information('fy1 4bj', 'ls1 5ns');
echo $info['distance'].' miles ' . 'That\'s about ' .$info['time'].' minutes drive from you';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo 'Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

This is the code that will work only if I comment out the second function.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM mileage";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?><table style="width:100%" border=1px><?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
$i=$i+1;
      if (isset($row['Start'])){$start = $row['Start'];}
      if (isset($row['Site'])){$finish2 = $row['Site'];}
      if (isset($lastsite)) {$finish=$lastsite;}
      if (isset($start) && isset($finish)){
 $info  = get_driving_information($start, $finish);} 
      if (isset($start) && isset($finish2)){
 //$info2 = get_driving_information($start, $finish2);
      }
  if ($i>1){


       ?>
      <td><?php echo  $start; ?></td> <td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/<?php echo $start . "/" . $lastsite ?>">
      Distance: <?php $drive=$info['distance'];
      echo $drive; ?></td></tr> <?php     
  }?>

      <tr><td> <?php echo $start ?></td><td><?php echo $finish2 ?> 
      </td><td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/<?php echo $start . "/" . $finish2 ?>">
      Distance:
        <?php


      $drive2=$info2['distance'];
      echo $drive2;
      ?> </td></tr><tr><td> <?php echo $finish2 ?></td><?php
      $lastsite=$finish2;
 }?>
</table>
```

Comment: Any errors thrown? Maybe increase the error reporting may indicate something.

Comment: nope no errors with  error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: You might be passing a blank string to google as a destination. If $row['Site'] is a blank string, it will still evaluate isset to TRUE (as it is not set to null). I would try checking or echoing your DB output to verify. You might want to use !empty() instead. Otherwise you might be passing some other kind of invalid input to the google API in which case calling invalid object resources in your code would cause a fatal error.

Comment: Thanks Daielml01 the problem was one of the postcodes wasn't a valid address.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really tried to fix your code, but generally speaking it should work. Here is a minimalist example of the PHP code that *does* run in a loop: [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jpk2-31it)

```
function gdi($url){
 $d=(new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url)))->route->leg;
 return array('from'=>$d->start_address,'to'=>$d->end_address,
                 'dist'=>$d->distance->text,'dur'=>$d->duration->text);
}
$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=fy1+4bj&destination=';

foreach (array('ls1+5ns','Bünde','Goslar') as $dest){
 $g=gdi($url.$dest);    
 echo "The distance from $g[from] to $g[to] is $g[dist] and driving it takes about $g[dur].\n";
}
```